# Android - Scroll Parent Layout with ViewPager

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to build a layout with a viewpager and a CoordinatorLayout. The general structure of my view is:

parent_frag.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
  <ScrollView>
    <ImageView/>
    <LinearLayout>
       <TextView/>
     </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/>
  </ScrollView>
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And programmatically, I add another fragment to the view pager which makes the view larger than the screen. If I add a ScrollView to the content in the ViewPager, then it works fine. However, it only scrolls the content in the viewPager but not the whole screen with everything content above the viewpager.

How can I get the scrollview to scroll the entire view but not just the viewpager? I've seen other questions posted over the years but I feel they don't apply to my question as most of the ones I've seen are for scrolling the whole viewpager which takes up the full screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add multiple child in ScrollView. Add one linearlayout as one child of ScrollView Your structure should be

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
  <ScrollView>
    <LinerLayout>
      <ImageView/>
      <LinearLayout>
      <TextView/>
    </LinearLayout>
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager/>
    <LinerLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: thanks yeah. i was actually just trying to illustrate the main point being my issue with the scroller and view pager. agreed, that there can only be one child to a scroll view. i started looking into `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

`<CoordinatorLayout>
<AppBarLayout>
<CollapsingToolbarLayout>
<RelativeLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar> 
....
`

Comment: but it's not going well. i basically need <LinearLayout> that contains some header user info and a picture that is about half the size of a phone screen to disappear when I scroll up so i can see content in the viewpager tab #1